# Add computed observable to items in array

Tags: knockout.js

In KnockoutJS, I try to add computed observables to each item of an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items().length; i++) {
    var item = items()[i];
    item.valid = ko.computed(function() {
        var valid = true;
        valid = valid && item.firstName() && item.firstName().length > 0;
        valid = valid && item.lastName() && item.lastName().length > 0;
        return valid;
    });
}
```

This always updates all occurances of `valid()` and it only works on the last item of the array.

I presume it's sort of context problem, but I don't get it.

The complete code can be found in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/ftaXe/6/).

#### Update

I found a solution based on mapping options [here](http://www.underwatergorilladome.com/how-to-use-knockouts-computed-observables-with-the-mapping-plugin/).

A jsfiddle based on the solution can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/PAhPq/2/).

Alas, this requires the mapping to be invoked differently for different data (in terms of need of valid property or not) from AJAX.

Is there a way that works after the mapping has been done?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net of your issue? You can fork off this one if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/yHXrg/

Comment: Added a simplified jsfiddle to the question.

Comment: @JasonMore please post your jsfiddle as answer and I'll mark it the answer. It lead me to the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to show a more clear example of what to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/s9Rmp/2/

Here is a snippet of live code I'm using now for mapping. It might help you going forward. The DisplayViewModel is the parent view model that eventually gets bound.

```
// helpers

var dateConvert = {
    create: function (options) {
        return new Date(parseInt(options.data.substr(6)));
    }
};

var viewModelConvert = function (viewModelType) {
    return {
        create: function (options) {
            return new viewModelType(options.data);
        }
    }
};

// View Models

var layoutViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.ShowText = ko.computed(function () {
        var val = self.ValueType();
        return val !== contentType.Image && val !== contentType.Html;
    });

};

var zoneViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
        {
            'Layouts': viewModelConvert(layoutViewModel)
        }, this);
};

var presentationViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    // Mapping
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
        {
            'Zones': viewModelConvert(zoneViewModel)
        }, this);
};

var eventViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
        {
            'Presentations': viewModelConvert(presentationViewModel),
            'EndDateTime': dateConvert,
            'StartDateTime': dateConvert
        }, this);
};

var fontViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.fontFace = ko.computed(function () {
        return "@font-face {font-family: '" + self.Name() + "'; src:url('" + settings.fontUrl + self.FileName() + "')}";
    });
};

var displayViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    this.init = function () {

    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
        {
            'Events': viewModelConvert(eventViewModel),
            'Fonts': viewModelConvert(fontViewModel)
        }, this);
};
```